# Does the method of assignment change how memory is allocated?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, memory

I had this done this assignment in the code:

```
const char* value = retCharPtrFunc();
```

Which had to be changed to:

```
const char* value;
if (true)
value = (retStringFunc()).c_str();
else
value = retCharPtrFunc();
```

And for some reason now this code is accessing more heap memory than before (using Address Sanitizer).

Heap memory is for pointers (dynamic alloc.) and it doesn't look like I have added more memory than before, just changing the assignments.

Is there any difference how these code are interpreted by the compiler and allocated memory?

To add more details:
The char* or the string that both the functions return are exactly same in length and only few characters vary which should not increase the allocation of memory.

The following are signatures of the functions (as asked in the comments):

```
const char* retCharPtrFunc() const;

string retStringFunc() const;
```

Desired behavior: need to understand why more memory is consumed if variables are same but assignment is different

Comment: Please show the signature of `retCharPtrFunc`.

Comment: @drescherjm both compile fine and results are as expected but it is heap that is taking more than it should

Comment: Neither of those mean its not UB as unfortunately sometimes UB works as expected. I too would like to see the signature of `retCharPtrFunc()`

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: the first example is calling `retCharPtrFunc` but the second is calling `retStringFunc`? these don't look equivalent, why are you surprised there is a difference?

Comment: @WernerHenze added the function signature

Comment: This really looks like you are storing a pointer to a freed string. If the return type of `retStringFunc` is `std::string`, you have a dangling pointer, and accessing that is UB. You are likely to find the expected string in its place, but it could be overwritten at any moment leading to weird behavior. Don't rely on UB.

Comment: @kmdreko because length of both the returns (whether string or char*) are same.

Comment: @chi yes return type is string. How do I fix that?

Comment: Please also add the signature of `retStringFunc`. As Richard Critten said: [mcve] please.

Comment: @WernerHenze done.

Comment: `value = (retStringFunc()).c_str();`  is definitely Undefined Behavior. The returned string from retStringFunc() goes out of scope causing the pointer in value to be dangling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're calling `.c_str()` on a temporary string; the temporary gets destroyed and now the C string pointer is invalid.

You should save the result of `retStringFunc()` in a variable. And you need to ensure that this variable doesn't go out of scope while you're using `value`.

```
std::string s;
const char *value;
if (true) {
    s = retStringFunc();
    value = s.c_str();
} else {
    value = retCharFunc();
}
```